# Show that $(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}, *)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}, *)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know I have to show

---

1) $1\in\mathbb{Q}$

2) $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ implies $a*b\in\mathbb{Q}$

3) $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ implies $a^{-1}\in\mathbb{Q}$

---

but I don't know how go about it. Can anyone give some hints or a place to start?

Comment: Which numbers are there in $\Bbb Q$? What is the multiplicative unit of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: I think stating these three facts suffices.  (In (1), I would rather say $1 \in (\Bbb{Q}^*, \times)$ though.)

Comment: Which of the three goals do you have trouble establishing?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm not really sure how to show (2)

Comment: What definition of $\mathbb Q$ are you using?

Comment: @lhf rationals without 0

Comment: @Nick: Do you know the rule $\frac ab \cdot \frac cd = \frac{ac}{bd}$?

Comment: In addition to Henning's comment, recall that the rational numbers are all numbers of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z},b\neq 0,$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Whenever you work with $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, you can rewrite it as $x=\frac{a}{b}$ with those conditions, and if you want to prove that $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, you prove that it can be written in that way. That will make proving $(2)$ and $(3)$ clearer.